# Making solr to understand English

Tags: solr, lucene, uima

I'm trying to setup solr that should understand English. For example I've indexed our company website (www.biginfolabs.com) or it could be any other website or our own data.

If i put some English like queries i should get the one word answer just what Google does;queries are:

- Where is India located.
- who is the father of Obama.

Workaround:

- Integrated UIMA,Mahout with solr(person name,city name extraction is done).
- I read the book called "Taming Text" and implemented https://github.com/tamingtext/book. But Did not get what i want.

Can anyone please tell how to move further. It can be anything our team is ready to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This task is called Named Entity Recognition. You can look up [this tutorial](http://searchhub.org/2013/06/27/poor-mans-entity-extraction-with-solr/) to see how they use Solr for extractic atomic elements in text into predefined categories such as the names of persons, organizations, locations, expressions of times, quantities, monetary values, percentages, etc. and then learning a model to answer queries.

Also have a look at [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/index.shtml) for more ideas on algorithms that you can use.